# how to programmatically increase/decrease volume using speech in Android

Tags: android-audiomanager

The goal here is to say "volume up" and for the volume to increase by 20% at a time by speaking that command for media playback. Not just to set it to max volume when the app starts. and conversely volume down. This is what I tried and it does not work.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


     // Without volume control UI
        To increase media player volume
         audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND)

     //To decrease media player volume
            audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND)
```

My app uses Speech commands too launch apps I want to add the functionality of volume control and I'm a lil stuck, most of the code uses intents like similar to this format for basic commands like time, for instance, works as follows

```
if (command.indexOf("time") != -1) {
                Date now = new Date();
                String time = formatDateTime(this, now.getTime(),
                        FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
                speak("the time is " + time);
```

I would like it to raise or lower by 20%  so I used the format of the following and can't get it to work Any help is appreciated..

```
else if (command.indexOf("Volume Up") !=-1) {

                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    intent.audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND));
            }
```

Comment: "This method has no effect if the device implements a fixed volume policy as indicated by isVolumeFixed()."

Comment: Is there a way around it?  Or a better method to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "as indicated by isVolumeFixed()" query that to find out if its your problem. The work around is to tell the user to change their settings.